# Can I make a MySQL TEMPORARY TABLE non-temporary?

Tags: mysql, sql, ansi-sql

Is there a simple ALTER TABLE that will allow this, or should I simply CREATE ... LIKE ...; ... INSERT SELECT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temp tables live in tempdb, not your data files, so you're gonna have to recreate it there. Try:

```
SELECT * INTO MyTable FROM #tempTable
```

Comment: Will this create MyTable?

Comment: Yes, it will create MyTable.